# Initial state of autoCreateRowSorter in Swing JTable

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have this JTable on my Swing app with the autoCreateRowSorter enabled. My table only has 3 columns, two strings and one int, it works well for all of them when I click the column headers.

However, I'm looking for way to do it programatically. I wanted to set the "initial state" for this table. With the Windows look and feel, the column header (when sorted) has a little arrow showing the sort order. But at startup that doesn't show, I have to do one initial click.

How can I do that by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programaticallly sort the table you can do something like:

```
DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter());
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add( new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING) );
sorter.setSortKeys(list);
sorter.sort();
```

Comment: So many lines for such a simple thing, I hate Java lol. Thanks :)

Comment: @Nazgulled there's always a longer path to reach simple goals :-) See the Richard's for the shortest version in core. JXTable has convenience api on the table level for an even shorter solution

Answer (score 1):

I think `DefaultRowSorter#toggleSortOrder(int column)` will do the work

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the `DefaultRowSorter` interface.

```
table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(column);
```

works as well.